# how to dump mysql database if it cannot create a tcp ip socket (or how to fix it)

Tags: mysql, windows-xp, socket

while trying to run mysql/mysqldump i get an error

"Can't create TCP/IP socket(10106) when trying to connect"

is it possible to fix it? or is it possible to make a backup of mysql dbs in this situation somehow? what if i copy paste whole mysql install on another computer? (i know it's a wrong way but if it's the only way..)

why i need it is because my win xp installation got broken and i want to reinstall it - i cannot start apache(alloc_listener:failed to get a socket for 127.0.0.1) and connect to internet anymore (wireless connection constantly says it cannot renew ip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shutdown mysql and just take backup of mysql database files - to be on the safe side take all.

if you use innodb DO TAKE innodb log files as well : ib_logfileX and innodb data file: ibdataX

preferably try on another machine if data is readable and then peacefully reinstall the whole thing.

Comment: Make sure MySQL is shut down before doing this.  Otherwise, you can get a corrupt backup (especially with InnoDB).  Alternatively, look for one of the "hot copy" solutions out there.

Comment: @Matt Solnit you are absolutly right. i've corrected my answer.